# Where to refer to get a list of Primefaces effects

Tags: primefaces

I referred the Prime-faces [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/galleria.html) and [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/galleria.jsf)  of Galleria and imageSwitch, still I could not find the possible values for the effect attribute. Is there any place where I can refer to get the complete list of possible values for every attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the User Guide

Galleria:

> Effects There are four different options for the animation to display
> when switching images;
>
> • fade
>
> • flash
>
> • pulse
>
> • slide